# What are bundles? Can we create custom bundles?

Tags: entities

Does all nodes have bundles? Also can we create custom  bundles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Bundles are an implementation of an entity type to which fields can be
>   attached. You can consider bundles as subtypes of an entity. With
>   content nodes, for example, you can generate subtypes like articles,
>   blogs, or products. Not all entity types have bundles, however. For
>   example, users do not have separate bundles or subtypes. With bundles,
>   you can have as many subtypes as you want. Then, using the Field
>   system, you can add additional fields to those bundles such as file
>   download field for Articles and location fields for Users.

Read more [here](http://drupal.org/node/1261744) and a [good article](http://joshaust.in/2012/06/entities-and-bundles-in-drupal-7/) that i found. Hope it helps :-)