# Entity record field UI

Tags: 7, entities

How I can have fields for each **record** of an **entity type** *uniquely*?
I have already tried something like this:

```
$items['admin/structure/basic_example/manage/%/fields'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example fields',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('field_ui_field_overview_form', 'basic_example'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer basic_example entities'),
);
```

Comment: What do you expect that code to do? What does it do?

Comment: I expected that when I call localhost/admin/structure/basic_example/manage/1/fields I get the fields list ui for the record 1 of the entity type basic_example

Comment: Oh right, no that won't happen. Fields are per bundle (content type), not per entity, so you can't manage fields for a single entity. Theroretically speaking it would be possible to change how that works, but it would take a _lot_ of custom code

Comment: Could you point me than to a good website where it explains bundles in Drupal?

Comment: Assuming you think _this_ is a good website ;) ... http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48128/what-are-bundles-can-we-create-custom-bundles